# How to obtain transition amplitude from non-Hermitian operator using only expectation values?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space, computational-physics

First of all, I'm aiming to use this approach on quantum computers - that means, no statevector is available in non-simulated run, as the only tool we have is measurement of expectation values. In other words, I need to obtain the transition probability via only expectation values.

Let's say, I have the operators
$$
\begin{align}
\widehat{E}_{00} &= \widehat{a}_0^\dagger \widehat{a}_0 + \widehat{a}_2^\dagger \widehat{a}_2\\
\widehat{E}_{01} &= \widehat{a}_0^\dagger \widehat{a}_1 + \widehat{a}_2^\dagger \widehat{a}_3^\dagger,
\end{align}
$$

where $\widehat{E}_{00}$ is Hermitian, while $\widehat{E}_{01}$ is not. Now, I need to obtain transition amplitudes $\langle \psi_0 | \widehat{E}_{00} | \psi_1 \rangle$ and $\langle \psi_0 | \widehat{E}_{01} | \psi_1 \rangle$.

As I said in the beginning, I can perform measurements of expectation values only (I work with quantum circuits, NOT with statevectors themselves), so I need to formulate the problem that way. For that, I tried to adopt the approach by Nakanishi et al. (https://journals.aps.org/prresearch/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevResearch.1.033062), i.e. the formula
$$\begin{align}
Re\left(\langle \psi_i |  \widehat{A} | \psi_j \rangle \right) &= \langle +^x_{ij} | \widehat{A} | +^x_{ij} \rangle - \frac{1}{2} \langle \psi_i |  \widehat{A} | \psi_i \rangle - \frac{1}{2} \langle \psi_j | \widehat{A} | \psi_j \rangle\\
|+^x_{ij}\rangle &= \frac{|\psi_i\rangle + | \psi_j \rangle}{\sqrt{2}}.
\end{align}
$$

For the simplicity, let's limit the question on the situation with purely real transition amplitudes.

**Now, the approach only seems to be working for $\widehat{E}_{00}$ and not for $\widehat{E}_{01}$. Is it because of it not being Hermitian? And if it is, is there any simple workaround for that?**

---

#### Numerical example (full Python code below)

Let's have our vectors
$$
\begin{align}
|\psi_0 \rangle &= [0, 0, 0, 0,
                0, -0.943723401, -0.169195869, 0,
                0, -0.169187622,  0.228329692, 0,
                0,  0, 0, 0]\\
| \psi_1 \rangle &= [0, 0, 0, 0,
                0,  0.304156221, -0.635709768, 0,
                0, -0.635716240,  0.315003089, 0,
                0,  0, 0, 0]\\
| +^x_{ij} \rangle &= [0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, -0.452242290, -0.569154235, 0,
        0, -0.569152979,  0.384194294,  0,
       0, 0, 0, 0]
\end{align}
$$

and our operators, expanded in *sto-3g* basis set into a matrix form

$$
\widehat{E}_{00} = \begin{bmatrix}
0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0\\0.0&1.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0\\0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0\\0.0&0.0&0.0&1.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0\\0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&1.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0\\0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&2.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0\\0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&1.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0\\0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&2.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0\\0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0\\0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&1.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0\\0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0\\0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&1.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0\\0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&1.0&0.0&0.0&0.0\\0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&2.0&0.0&0.0\\0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&1.0&0.0\\0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&2.0
\end{bmatrix}\\
\widehat{E}_{01} = \begin{bmatrix}
0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0\\0.0&0.0&1.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0\\0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0\\0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0\\0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&1.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0\\0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&1.0&0.0&0.0&1.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0\\0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&1.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0\\0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&1.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0\\0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0\\0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&1.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0\\0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0\\0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0\\0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0\\0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&1.0&0.0\\0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0\\0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0&0.0
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

Now, the reference values are
$$
\begin{align}
\langle \psi_0 | \widehat{E}_{00} | \psi_1 \rangle &= -0.3589639 \\
\langle \psi_0 | \widehat{E}_{01} | \psi_1 \rangle &= 1.09328263.
\end{align}
$$

Utilizing the formula, we're obtaining the following results:
$$
\begin{align}
\langle \psi_0 | \widehat{E}_{00} | \psi_1 \rangle &= 1.0569178 - \frac{1.8384794}{2} - \frac{0.9932841}{2} &= -0.3589639\\
\langle \psi_0 | \widehat{E}_{01} | \psi_1 \rangle &= 0.0774595 - \frac{0.242077}{2} - \frac{-0.7872152}{2} &= 0.350028
\end{align}
$$

Now, we can see, that while the formula works for $\widehat{E}_{00}$, it unfortunately doesn't for $\widehat{E}_{01}$. What am I doing wrong?

---

#### Full Python code

````
from icecream import ic

sv1 = np.array([4.73817313e-17, -1.88804229e-19, -8.06897788e-17, 1.08186793e-17,
                -5.84051517e-17, -9.43723401e-01, -1.69195869e-01, 3.34290134e-17,
                -9.56955495e-17, -1.69187622e-01, 2.28329692e-01, -2.64324650e-17,
                -2.77555756e-17, 5.70234410e-17, -4.51439009e-17, -1.64830458e-16])

sv2 = np.array([-5.10255268e-17, 1.01095830e-16, -1.46370933e-16, 8.30376837e-18,
                8.82088996e-17, 3.04156221e-01, -6.35709768e-01, -1.56662176e-16,
                -6.93517637e-17, -6.35716240e-01, 3.15003089e-01, 1.94589958e-16,
                4.94863038e-17, 1.97127944e-17, -3.40287898e-17, -8.07113264e-17])

plus_X = (sv1 + sv2) / np.sqrt(2)

E00 = np.array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
                [0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
                [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
                [0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
                [0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
                [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 2., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
                [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
                [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 2., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
                [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
                [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
                [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
                [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
                [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
                [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 2., 0., 0.],
                [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0.],
                [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 2.]])

E01 = np.array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
                [0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
                [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
                [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
                [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
                [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
                [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
                [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
                [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
                [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
                [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
                [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
                [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
                [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0.],
                [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
                [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])

ic(sv1 @ E00 @ sv2)
ic(sv1 @ E01 @ sv2)

ic(plus_X @ E00 @ plus_X)
ic(sv1 @ E00 @ sv1)
ic(sv2 @ E00 @ sv2)

ic(plus_X @ E01 @ plus_X)
ic(sv1 @ E01 @ sv1)
ic(sv2 @ E01 @ sv2)

ic(plus_X @ E00 @ plus_X - 0.5 * (sv1 @ E00 @ sv1) - 0.5 * (sv2 @ E00 @ sv2))
ic(plus_X @ E01 @ plus_X - 0.5 * (sv1 @ E01 @ sv1) - 0.5 * (sv2 @ E01 @ sv2))
```
````

Comment: @CosmasZachos Oh, my mistake, I made a typo... It's fixed now. Thank you!

Comment: Are the sub-machine precision values in the `sv1` and `sv2` lists intentional (e.g., for producing a valid solution)? You wrote in the MathJax that it's 0, but $10^{-17}$ is small but also non-zero.

Comment: @KyleKanos Yes, I wanted to make the text more readable - the "real" values I obtained from a larger problem are in the full code.

Comment: @KyleKanos Otherwise, for computation I'd use $10^{-17}$ etc.